# Android + Bitrise + Codecov ignore is not working

Tags: android, code-coverage, bitrise, codecov

I am new bee in the codecov implementation. I am implementing codecov for my android library. I have read the codecov documentation, I have added the "Jococo" plugin in gradle. Locally everything working perfect, On the bitrise also Jococo gradlew commands working fine.

I have added codecov.yml file in my main directory and bitrise log is also saying yml detected. But I have added ignore command in that file which is not at all working.

```
codecov:
  token: "my_token"

ignore:
  - "app/src/main"
```

Comment: Tom from Codecov here. I think we'd need to dig into this more, can you open a support issue on our [community boards](https://community.codecov.io)?

Comment: Hi @ThomasHu, I have raised this issue on the community board and that issue is on hold for moderator verification. Please look into it, Hope i will get the solution earliest.

one more thing, I have check the example all are including travis. Are we have any native example and native development without any vendor partnership.